# Is it bad practice to create the AdalTokenCache as an SQL Database in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

My MVC web application uses Azure AD Authentication.  Initially when you run the wizard on your project to set this up for you it creates an `mdf` database file in your project for the `AdalTokenCache`.  This isn't compatible with Azure as you can't use local MDF files.

What I have done is created the `AdalTokenCache` as a database in my Azure portal and I'm using that instead (which works fine).  My question is, is this bad practice and if so what's the best way of handling it?

Comment: "Bad practice" and "best way" are subjective.. note that people have also used [table storage](https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2016/12/using-azure-table-storage-as-adal-token-cache/) and [Redis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2016/09/19/using-redis-as-adal-token-cache/) for this.

Comment: Other option is to use "Naive Session" from http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/09/the-new-token-cache-in-adal-v2/. See also [Is it OK to use NaiveSessionCache from Azure-Samples Azure Active Directory OpenId Connect](//stackoverflow.com/q/41864737) question